# Starting an endless loop from an async function

Tags: python, python-asyncio, apscheduler

I'm trying to periodically query an API. My code structure is as follows:

```
async def QueryData(): 
    print(datetime.datetime.now())

async def main():
    await TestApiConnection()
    
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone="Europe/Berlin")
    scheduler.add_job(QueryData, 'cron', minute='0-59')
    scheduler.start()
    try:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
        scheduler.shutdown(wait=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The following error is thrown if I run this:

> in run_forever
> assert self._self_reading_future is None AssertionError

If I turn the main function into a synchronous function, the *QueryData* job starts, by the result of *TestApiConnection* is not awaited anymore.

```
async def QueryData(): 
    print(datetime.datetime.now())

def main():
    TestApiConnection()
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**So how do I start the job from the async main method? Or should I restructure the code?**

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example, I can not run and debug your code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call `run_forever()` from the *inside* of an event loop, that function is intended for sync code that needs to fire up an event loop. When you use `asyncio.run()` you can simply await something that will never end. For example, you can replace `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()` with:

```
await asyncio.Event().wait()
```

Also note that you don't need the `pass` before the call to `scheduler.shutdown()`. The sole purpose of the `pass` keyword is as an inert stand-in for places where the grammar requires a statement, and you have nothing to provide.